# Did the Cretaceous-Paleogene extinction event cause miniature tidal waves?

Tags: meteors

This could be considered on-topic for [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/), but I'm putting it here because I'm interested primarily in the dynamics of the impact.

65 million years ago, [a large body crashed down onto Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous%E2%80%93Paleogene_extinction_event), causing an [impact winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_winter) and driving the dinosaurs (and other forms of life) extinct. The [Chicxulub crater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_crater) is thought to have been formed by the impact. Given that part of the crater is in the Gulf of Mexico, it seems safe to assume that (even with continental drift) that part of the object landed in the water. Did the impact of this object cause any immediate changes in the water around it? In other words, did it cause miniature (or full-size) tsunamis? A follow-up question would be: How big would an object have to be to cause such effects?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_crater#Effects), by the way, says yes, but I'd like some more authoritative sources, especially peer-reviewed ones.

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dcp0JhwNgmE)?

Comment: @KyleKanos It's looking like yes.

Comment: Suggestion to the question (v1): Replace the word _tidal wave_ with _tsunami._

Comment: At a quick Google I can't find any good links, but I'm 99% sure there is geological evidence for debris caused by tidal waves from the Chicxulub impact. What's more the thickness of the debris layer decreases with distance from the impact point as it should do.